# Laravel - How to update array value in laravel session?

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm creating cart functionality in laravel 5.3. when user add product to cart it's basically create session and add product to that session.

let's start with example on that I'm working.

when user add product to cart I am passing required parameter to controller function and then it's store in session. so my controller function is :

```
public function add_cart(Request $request){


    $product = [
        'sku' => $request['sku'],
        'price' => $request['price'],
        'quantity' => $request['quantity'],
        'brand_id' => $request['brand_id'],
        'brand_name' => $request['brand_name'],
        'brand_img' => $request['brand_img']
    ];

   // dd($product);
    if($request->session()->has('add_to_cart')){
        $request->session()->push('add_to_cart', $product);
    }else{
        $request->session()->push('add_to_cart', $product);
    }


    return count($request->session()->get('add_to_cart'));

}
```

so after add product to **add_to_cart** session my session is look like this :

```
array:2 [▼
0 => array:6 [▼
"sku" => ""
"price" => " "
"quantity" => "1"
"brand_id" => "14"
"brand_name" => "The Body Shop"
"brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c623c560f5.jpg"
 ]
1 => array:6 [▼
"sku" => "ffs002000"
"price" => "2000"
"quantity" => "1"
"brand_id" => "47"
"brand_name" => "The Four Fountains Spa"
"brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c47b5a27eb.jpg"
]
]
```

using this I can show all cart product in cart page also done with subtotal , tax and total of payment functionality.

Now problem is if I want to update quantity of **brand_id : 14** how can I get array of product from session where brand_id is 14 ? and after geting that product array how to update only quantity value from that array ? or may be we can replace whole product array with new one but how to find that product array from session ?

don't have any idea. I search on laravel documentation but not get any method to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing that, You can crate a simple function to update the session for you..

Here is an example.

```
public function updateQuantityByBrand($brand_id, $quantity){
   $cartItems = session()->get('add_to_cart');

   foreach($cartItems as $item){
      if($item["brand_id"] == $brand_id){
          $item["quantity"] = $quantity;
      }
   }

   return session("add_to_cart", $cartItems);
}
```

Comment: your answer is right. but I have one issue is that how to pass brand_id to controller function ? because on cart page all I'm getting with foreach loop so how can I determine that for which brand_id quantity is changed?

Comment: this function can be private on your controller. then call it from the `public function add_cart(Request $request)` function . after you define the array of `$product` do this: `$this->updateQuantityByBrand($product["brand_id"], $product["quantity"]);`